# How to autosubmit form before an actionlink invokes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Item",new{Id=ItemId),null}
```

There is a form at the top of the page which I need to save when the user clicks on this link and before the "Edit" action invokes.

So something to achieve this when the user clicks on the link may look like:

```
Save MasterForm
Carry on through to "Edit" Action on "Item" controller with "Id" parameter.
```

My instinct tells me that I may be looking for some JS??? Not sure.

Any help hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this would be:

1. Add a click listener to the action link
2. Submit the form using Ajax
3. Follow the link manually by setting `window.location`

It would probably be a good idea to display some kind of spinner or popup while the form is submitting, so that the user knows something is happening.

For step 1, you need to select the `<a>` tags, so I suggest adding a class:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Item",new{Id=ItemId),new{@class="edit-link"}}
```

Then add some Javascript to intercept the click:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-link", function(e) {
    // stop the browser from following the link
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkUrl = $(this).attr("href");

    // submit the form via an Ajax post (assuming the form has "id=MasterForm")
    var form = $("#MasterForm");
    $.post(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), function() {

        // when complete, navigate to the original link
        window.location = linkUrl;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks good. However why is the @class="edit-link" in the new{} bit as these are parms to the actions. Should @class="edit-link" not replace "null" after new{}. Apologies if I am getting my thoughts confused.

Comment: @SamJolly no you're right, that was a mistake.  I meant to put that into the "HTML attributes" parameter.  I think it's right now -- the 5th argument in this overload:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: OK that is now working great. Thank you for the very timely and comprehensive advice. Really appreciated.

Comment: Just a cheeky extra question related to this. You mention a progress spinner. What would the additional code look like? I assume it would be a part of the JQuery? Thanks.

Comment: @SamJolly not built in to JQuery, but there are lots of plugins (eg http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/).  You could just do a simple overlay of full-screen partially opaque div with an animated gif spinner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Item",new{Id=ItemId),new {@id='btn-link'}}
```

In JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#btn-link').click(function(e){
    saveMasterFormDetails();
});

});

function saveMasterFormDetails(){

   var masterForm=$('#masterForm');

  $.post(url,masterForm.serialize(), function(data){
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Murali, I think I had 2 good solutions here, but alas I went with the other. Shame I cannot tick both! But a big thank you anyway.